# Pairwise similarity based cluster visualization question

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-computing, visualization

Not sure if I'm in the right exchange to post this question but feel free to redirect me!

I am fairly new to clustering techniques and would love some help.

I have a pandas dataframe with the following fields: user1, user2, similarity_score, and city.

I have made my own clusters within each city by building upon pairs (i.e. A-B have a high score, B-C and A-C does, as well, thus, C is added to the cluster, too).

However, I would really love to hear some thoughts on how to visualize this - what kind of a visualization would you use?  I honestly just don't know how because my data is formatted so that similarity scores are pairwise.

Again, thank you so much for the help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Are your similarity scores between zero and one - or do they take on more general values?